# Can users create their own AWS IAM accounts so that curl POSTs to my API can be authenticated?

Tags: amazon-web-services, curl, firebase-cloud-messaging

I've been working on an iOS app that does unidirectional FCM to my app. The platform itself isn't really relevant, it could just as easily be an Android app. So far it's working great both using Swift in-app to send messages and get updated tokens if they expire. I also have a way for the device token to be extracted from the app so that the device can be used as a destination in the FCM.

I can currently use `curl` to send FCM because I have access to the Auth key. The problem is that FCM requires the Auth key to be in the `curl` header, and I don't know how to allow users to send messages with `curl` and not give them the Auth key.

AWS Lambda seems to be the solution, but I can't find how to allow users to create their own accounts.

The endgame for what I want to do is to allow users to write their own scripts or use IFTTT to send messages to my app. The app will ingest the message, and I can't speak about the rest of the project because it's proprietary.

Solving this problem without having to run my own server has been frustrating. I've run servers in the past, and this app is so simple and small, that the work involved in setting up and maintaining the server myself isn't worth the trouble. I'm looking into possibly using AWS for this to alleviate a lot of the stress.

My idea is this:

- User creates an account themselves.
- The user has to put in their credentials in the `curl` POST header in order
  to access the API (let's call it `pushfcm`).
- If the authentication validates, `pushfcm` will ingest the data from the user's POST, and create a new POST for FCM, adding the FCM Auth token, and send the FCM message to Firebase.

The process is not the problem. The brick wall I keep hitting is that AWS Lambda requires IAM, but I can't find any documentation on how to allow users to create their own IAM account - I have to create it for them. That's not practical. Firebase allows users to create their own accounts, but AWS doesn't interact with that data, and Firebase doesn't allow you to run code on their server, you have to run the code on your own server or AWS. I found a lot of articles on how to access Firebase from AWS, but no idea how to allow users to create accounts. I don't want bad actors (as they're called) to access the `pushfcm` API without authentication.

So, to sum up - AWS allows you to run the code you need (in my case, Python), but I can't find how to allow users to create their own accounts so that the `curl` POSTs to my API can be authenticated.

Is there some way to break this stalemate without running the code on my own server?

Comment: You shoudn't be using AWS iam accoutns as your app's accounts. Its bad practice and security issue. Use cognito for user accounts.